# JQuery Gantt Chart - Variables as Values

Tags: jquery, variables, gantt-chart

I am trying to manipulate a jquery gantt chart I found online (here: http://www.maro-z.com/examples/jquery.gantt/) as it fits my need perfectly in terms of its simplicity and how light weight it is.

Is it possible to use variables instead of values in jquery? The following code is used to create the gantt:

```
  $("#gantt").gantt({
    'tasks':[
        { 'titles': 'Task01', 'start_date': '20130323', 'end_date': '20130323' },
        { 'titles': 'Task02', 'start_date': '20130327', 'end_date': '20130327' },
        { 'titles': 'Task03', 'start_date': '20130406', 'end_date': '20130406' }
    ]
});
```

I want to replace each { 'titles': 'Task01', 'start_date': '20130323', 'end_date': '20130323' } with something like:

```
  for(i in title){
                { 'titles': title[i], 'start_date': startdate[i], 'end-date': enddate[i] },
                }
```

Is this possible?

Many Thanks in advance for an assistance :)

Karl.

Answer (score 0):

Was going about this the wrong way. I needed an Object, not a string. The following works a treat:

```
    GanttOptions[i] = new Object();
    GanttOptions[i]['titles'] = title[i];
    GanttOptions[i]['start_date'] = startdate[i];
    GanttOptions[i]['end_date'] = enddate[i];

$("#gantt").gantt({
    'tasks':GanttOptions
});
```